# Return only matched part of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string

```
var v = "09/30/2016 12:00am - 2:00am";
```

I need to get only date part of this string : `"09/30/2016"`

For it I have regex

```
var dateFormatRegex = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)\d\d$/ig;
```

But it only match string if there are only date string.

What should I add to my regex to get `09/30/2016` from string `09/30/2016 12:00am - 2:00am`?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? `v.split(' ')[0]`

Comment: To get that from a string in a known good format you would `var datePart = v.substr(0, 10);`

Comment: Take a look at the [`String.match` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: @ThinkingMedia, maybe you are right, but I affraid of it a bit )

Comment: @demo - If you're not afraid of dabbling in regular expressions, using `split()` will be a breeze; )

Comment: Remove the `$` from the end of your regex if you want to match on other strings that are not just a date.

Comment: Type your regexp into regex101.com, and then read the description it gives you real, real carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there!

Your only mistake is that you've put a `$` at the end of your regex, which makes it not match strings of the kind you posted.

Using [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return an array of matched groups - of which in this case you only have one, which you can then return with `matches[0]`

```
var dateFormatRegex = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)\d\d/ig;
// removed $ as in the target strings there is still stuff after the date

var v = "09/30/2016 12:00am - 2:00am";
var matches = v.match(dateFormatRegex);
var date = matches[0]; // === 09/30/2016"
```

Comment: That's a separate question altogether so please create a new question for that